# WordPress listing all/selected pages in A-Z index

Tags: wordpress

I want to list all pages as well as selected pages in A-Z listing in WordPress. I know there are a number of plugins available, but I want this without a plugin.

Update
sorry if question is not clear, i want A-Z listing like attached image [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved this issue,
just need to put if condition, here is the code

```
$arr[0] = array(2=>2983);
$arr[1] = array(2=>2981);
$arr[2] = array('A'=>20);
$arr[3] = array('A'=>25);

print "<pre>";
print_r($arr);

$newArry = array();
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {

        if (array_key_exists($key, $newArry)) {
            //$newArry[$key] = array($value);
            array_push($newArry[$key], $value);
        } else {
            $newArry[$key] = array($value);
        }
        echo "<br/> Key ".$key ." => Value ".$value;
        //print_r($b);
    }

}

print_r($newArry);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a WP_Query, as page is simply a post type.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$pages = $query->posts;
```

See [WP_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters).